# Зависание FFmpeg/ffplay при проигрывании rtmp

Tags: ffmpeg, rtmp

Имеется rtmp-поток. После запуска ffmpeg, последний останавливается и начинает играть в молчанку. Как ему указать, что если данных нет (ну или хотя бы по истечению какого-то времени), то следует завершить работу? Не надеюсь на ссылку к C API, хотя бы просто на ключ к консоли. Обыскался в мануале, попробовал некоторые ключи, но ничего не помогло.

Скриншот демонстрирует проблему:

[image: демонстрация проблемы]

Одни нули и ни на что не реагирует. Только православный CTRL+C.

**Update:**
Аналогичная ситуация возникает и при использовании C API ffmpeg версии 2.6 (последняя на сегодня). Контекст выполнения программы входит в `avformat_open_input` и на этом всё. Если программа имеет графический интерфейс пользователя, то он "замораживается" (в линукс), либо пишет, что программа не отвечает (в виндовс). Решением может послужить перенос кода ffmpeg в отдельный тред или даже процесс, чтобы, установив собственный таймер, ликвидировать этот поток, либо процесс принудительно. Однако очевидно, что это скорее полумера, которая по своей сути больше напоминает т.н. костыль, нежели чем эффективное решение.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FFmpeg, для работы, может использовать две реализации RTMP: свою встроенную, которая активна по умолчанию, и при помощи librtmp. Последняя должна принудительно включаться опцией `--enable-librtmp`.

Все встроенные механизмы FFmpeg могут использовать пользовательский [interrupt колбек](http://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/3.0/structAVIOInterruptCB.html). Установить его можно для формата используя поле [AVFormatContext::interrupt_callback](http://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/3.0/structAVFormatContext.html#a5b37acfe4024d92ee510064e80920b40).

Встроенная реализация RTMP его обрабатывает (как минимум, я чинил в 2014 году утечку файловых дескрипторов в `rtmp_open()` на подключении при срабатывании этого колбека), а реализация при помощи librtmp - [нет](http://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/3.0/librtmp_8c_source.html#l00095), просто потому, что вся кухня происходит внутри librtmp (из всех колбеков, которые можно ей задать - колбек для логирования).

Проверить, с какой реализацией rtmp собран FFmpeg, можно запустив его без параметров и поискать строку `--enable-librtmp`:

> $ ffmpeg
>
> ffmpeg version 3.0 Copyright (c) 2000-2016 the FFmpeg
>   developers
>
> built with gcc 4.8 (Ubuntu 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.1)
>
> configuration: --prefix=/usr --libdir=/usr/lib/
>   --incdir=/usr/include/ffmpeg3.0 --datadir=/usr/share/ffmpeg3.0 --docdir=/usr/share/doc/ffmpeg3.0 --enable-shared --enable-avresample --disable-stripping --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-nonfree --enable-runtime-cpudetect --build-suffix=.ffmpeg3.0 --progs-suffix=3.0 --enable-postproc --enable-x11grab --enable-avisynth --enable-bzlib --enable-fontconfig --enable-frei0r --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libfaac --enable-libfdk_aac --enable-libflite --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse **--enable-librtmp** --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzmq --enable-libzvbi --enable-openal --enable-opengl --enable-pthreads --enable-vaapi --enable-vdpau --enable-zlib --enable-debug=3

По поводу разницы, я особо не могу сказать: внутренняя более фичаста и функциональна, развивается, но испытывает больше проблем при publishing потока: librtmp поддерживает более навороченные схемы URL, которые особо любит Wowza. librtmp же находится в состоянии стагнации, развития нет, очень часто случаются такие проблемы с тайм-аутами (нет возможности поставить колбек на чтение). В своём PPA я планирую отказаться от сборки с librtmp в пользу встроенной поддержки.

Кроме того, внутренняя реализация поддерживает listen, чего категорически нет в librtmp. Т.е. можно тестировать схемы, где ffmpeg будет выступать в роли эдакого стримингового сервера.

Answer (score 1):

`stimeout` пробовали? Из [доки](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-protocols.html#rtsp):

> stimeout
>       Set socket TCP I/O timeout in microseconds.

Comment: Ранее не пробовал, но не пошло. В этом случае не показывает даже строку с нулями и начинающуюся с "nan ... ". Просто как будто висит.

Comment: @alexis031182 Вы какое значение таймаута задали?

Comment: В доках сказано, что там в микросекундах. Попробовал разные от секунды до десяти. Просто висит.

Comment: А у Вас получилось? Я ссылку на поток не публикую, чтобы гугл не проиндексировал. Если есть возможность, перепечатайте со скрина, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 1):

Попытался с помощью отладчика хотя бы локализовать место проблемы. Проверял в линуксе, но так как поведение и результат в виндовсе те же самые, то моё заключение скорее всего справедливо и для этой оси.

В случае с данной ссылкой (да собственно как и с любой другой) происходит открытие сокета и попытка чтения хотя бы одного rtmp-пакета, который бы позволил начать читать заголовки тех потоков, что раздаются с обозначенного ресурса. В случае, если что-то в схеме общения идёт не так, например, обрыв связи и/или превышение времени ожидания пакетов, то автоматом в цикле повторяются необходимые шаги.

Но этот цикл становится и камнем преткновения в случае, если сервер, который доступен и без проблем коннектится, абсолютно ничего не возвращает в ответ. То есть соединение установлено, всё хорошо, шлём ему запрос на получение заголовков, а в ответ тишина. Отсюда получается, что все тайминги, которые можно устанавливать для того же консольного ffplay, они прекрасно работают, но становятся в данной ситуации совершенно бесполезны, поскольку цикл уровнем выше раз за разом повторяет одну и ту же задачу - прочитать (согласно правилам протокола) хотя бы один пакет от сервера.

Получается, что в данной ситуации виновны, вроде бы как, обе стороны. Клиентская (ffmpeg) жёстко опирается на "букву закона" (протокол), без предусмотрения вариации, когда сервер может попросту начхать на правила. А вторую сторону можно обвинить, собственно, как раз за это начхание. Обязательно должен быть ответ, что, мол, не дам тебе видео, отвяжись. И тогда всё бы работало и интерфейс у конечного пользователя клиентского приложения не замирал.

Дислокация проблемы (файл "rtmpproto.c"):

```
static int get_packet(URLContext *s, int for_header)
Строка 2421, бесконечный цикл for(;;) {...}
```

Зацикливается на бесконечных вызовах функции `poll()` (файл "network.c", функция `ff_network_wait_fd_timeout()`), считывающей события ядра по определённому файловому дескриптору. В нашем случае - многострадальный сокет.

Comment: так ведь гугл говорит, что есть исходник -- https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/blob/master/ffplay.c Вот и подправьте его под себя (например, добавьте таймаут если данные не поступают).

Comment: @avp Да, исходники открыты, я потому и смог найти проблему. Решением теперь может быть простое добавление break в этот бесконечный цикл for, например, при определённом количестве попыток. Но всё это уже не важно. Хотелось понять, почему такое происходит. Ну и конечно очень плохо то, что придётся такой костыль добавлять, т.к. придётся его переносить, если в следующей версии ffmpeg разрабы не поправят ситуацию. Всё это не очень хорошо.